# How do you use node-sass in Scrimba as a dependency in a react template?

Tags: reactjs

Adding the node-sass package in scrimba quite easy but running the code i get an error:

[image]

Heres' my scrimba project: https://scrimba.com/c/cN3Wngc2

Comment: What is your folder structure

Comment: @ManishJangir styles/style.scss